# Function not returning correct result

Tags: c++, function, return

```
const int CHECK_MAX = 50;

void balanceAccount(double account)
{
    double start = 0;
    double interest = 0;
    double check[CHECK_MAX];

    account = (start - check[CHECK_MAX]) * (1 + interest);
    cout << account;
}

int main()
{
    int sub;
    double start = 0;
    double interest = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double check[CHECK_MAX];
    void balanceAccount(double);

    cin >> start;

   for (sub = 0; sub < CHECK_MAX; sub++)
    {
        cin >> check[sub];

        if (check[sub] == 0)
        {
            cout << "Thank you." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

   cin >> interest;

    if (interest == 0)
    {
        balanceAccount(total);
    }
        else
    {
            balanceAccount(total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this program is to prompt the user to enter a starting balance for a bank account, and then using an array, enter the individual amount for checks(up to 50) and have them subtracted from the initial balance. Then, if an interest value exists, that is multiplied to the total. The ending result is computed with the balanceAccount() function. I believe everything is working decently until the final computation. I keep getting the incorrect calculation. I'm eventually going to include a currency format to it but for now I just want it to compute correctly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you have an `if...else` at the end that does the same thing either way?

Comment: There are so many wrongs at so many levels. `total` is useless in `main`, `interest` is useless in `balanceAccount()`.

Comment: did you got it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
double check[CHECK_MAX];

account = (start - check[CHECK_MAX]) * (1 + interest);
```

Accessing `check[CHECK_MAX]` is not valid - it's running off the end of the array. C++ arrays are indexed 0-n-1, so the last item in the array is `check[CHECK_MAX-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

All of the variables in `balanceAccount()` are being initialized to zero, so the other variables in `main()` have no effect. To remedy this, pass the variables to `balanceAccount()` :

```
void balanceAccount(double localAccount, double localStart, double localInterest, double localCheck[])
{
    account = (start - check[CHECK_MAX]) * (1 + interest);
    cout << account;
}
```

You might also want to return `account`.'

This line:

```
account = (start - check[CHECK_MAX]) * (1 + interest);
```

goes past the end of the array, it should be:

```
account = (start - check[CHECK_MAX-1]) * (1 + interest);
```

I also don't know what you are doing with the `if...else` at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

change balanceAccount() method as below..

```
double balanceAccount(char account[])
{
    double start = 0;
    double interest = 0;
    double check[CHECK_MAX];

    double account = (start - check[CHECK_MAX-1]) * (1 + interest);
    cout << account;
}
```

For main `balanceAccount()`

`total = balanceAccount(check);`

Reason for passing `check` in `balanceAccount()`;you have created different  `check`'s  in `main()` and `balanceAccount()` and both are not same...

Also `check[CHECK_MAX]` operation is not valid... `0 to CHECK_MAX-1` are the valid memory location which counts upto `CHECK_MAX`...changed according in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Working code based on your statement Try this,

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int CHECK_MAX = 50;

void balanceAccount(double total,double interest)
{
    double account = (total) * (interest);
    cout << account;
}

int main()
{
    int sub;
    double start = 0;
    double interest = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double check[CHECK_MAX];
    void balanceAccount(double,double);

    cout << "Enter the beginning balance of the account at the beginning of the month." << endl;
    cin >> start;
    total = start;
    cout << "Enter the individual dollar amount of checks written this month." << endl;
    cout << "A maximum number of 50 checks is enforced." << endl;
    cout << "Enter a zero when you are finished entering check values." << endl;
    for (sub = 0; sub < CHECK_MAX; sub++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the dollar amount for the checks written, but one at a time." << endl;
            cin >> check[sub];
        total = total - check[sub];
        if (check[sub] == 0)
        {
            cout << "Thank you." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "If applicable, enter an interest rate." << endl;
    cout << "If there is no interest rate, enter a 0." << endl;
    cin >> interest;
    if(interest != 0)
    {
        cout << "Thank you." << endl;
        balanceAccount(total,interest);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Thank you." << endl;
        cout << total << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. Thank you! I'm very new to C++ and programming. This was a lot of help.